# Exception handler for unexpected expceptions in Spock

Tags: java, testing, spock

Is there a way to handle unexpected exceptions in Spock? My use-case is to make test failures where exceptions are thrown better human-readable. E.g. when a test fails with an `HttpClientErrorException`, I would like to have the status code and the body in the printed test output.

e.g.

```
when:
restTemplate.getForObject(url, String)

then:
noExceptionThrown()
```

Now the `getForObject()` call throws an `HttpClientErrorException` I want an output like this:

```
Expected no exception to be thrown, but got 'HttpClientErrorException'
  Status-Code: 400
  Body: '{"error": "parameter foo missing"}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [custom extension](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1/all_in_one.html#_writing_custom_extensions) to handle these exceptions yourself, you can't use `noExceptionThrown()` in this case, as this would prevent the exception to leave the feature method.

```
import spock.lang.*;
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.*;
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.*;

class NiceExceptionsInterceptor implements IMethodInterceptor {
    static final NiceExceptionsInterceptor INSTANCE = new NiceExceptionsInterceptor()
    
    void intercept(IMethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        try {
            invocation.proceed()
        } catch (SpecialException e) {
            throw new AssertionError("Special Exception happened: "+e.message)
        }
    }
}    

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target([ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD])  
@ExtensionAnnotation(NiceExceptionsExtensions)
@interface NiceExceptions {

}

class NiceExceptionsExtensions implements IAnnotationDrivenExtension<NiceExceptions> {
    @Override
    void visitSpecAnnotation(NiceExceptions annotation, SpecInfo spec) {
        spec.bottomSpec.allFeatures.featureMethod*.addInterceptor(NiceExceptionsInterceptor.INSTANCE)
    }

    @Override
    void visitFeatureAnnotation(NiceExceptions annotation, FeatureInfo feature) {
        feature.featureMethod.addInterceptor(NiceExceptionsInterceptor.INSTANCE)
    }
}

// ---- Usage DEMO 

class SpecialException extends Exception {
    SpecialException(String message) {
        super(message)
    }
}

@NiceExceptions
class ASpec extends Specification {

    def "spec level"() {
        when:
            throw new SpecialException("Foo")
        then:
            true
    }
}



class BSpec extends Specification {

    @NiceExceptions
    def "test level"() {
        when:
            throw new SpecialException("Foo")
        then:
            true
    }

}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJy9VEtz2jAQPse_YscnO02Ve_oYaHGmHIBMcA6dTg-KvQY1suSRhAmT4b9X8hsoaaaH6mD02Me3-30LywupDOhCJk-EU7Eilx88Vl_-oiWt76gQ0lDDpBg8S7UilV-maI5bqZ6I2gjDciT4bFDoN5vnMkXuTL2EU61hzhKMnhMsXEY9FQaVO0gFNhbHHIXRMJ2hWct0-PrigV3aIU0gY4LyV0JN58t4PP8awScQuD1vGIRV1OpTSpYCa9-CDkIpk6o79q3dhmDWSm41xO6HPnJs4Lll1G5wcqt3JIWSCWLa5HVrD_YpWUOwLDBhlHc4AcOjOFXSqqCx1qicUaSUrcJvfKF3XtOiQIHpDfjvLAmoNV3hIKtXf_dV-d7oHi2pzjHodneSs2RH7h_m8XQWhd4opmqFJvgR1SzFuwJJ_P0uuoLhzSyKvy0mP0MbdhS1Uhl3GgsOuegstE1QNT-jCR4RZtvg7f-sn97_QD59voliJYrO7OOh--emw6NFiUqxFHsllEwz4_p6Fjv0k3MFznIqMmmnDZMhce5MHqUxMnc2hHJ-i9RsFGqS1ZtaaZeEpkPFB2dVS1p5hw2Lr9bQZHtbGY1xVUmDzhVzcdEcDiH_O2KL-foa3tsFD06ZMIlmC2g5Ph0Fx1-qB_quG3xsGCyNYmIFrd6HPGwKVMHBIFQwRoegGwRjF7lLW6XJWPM_8FL3O8UMfMcucCyR-0HdqO0axc2ZsT2B699K6fdTaU591QZ7rG1_vvwd3XFZHWKD2vwnxN7-N2BKJuk)

You can write you handler logic and extract any information in the catch-block.

```
        catch (SpecialException e) {
            throw new AssertionError("Special Exception happened: "+e.message)
        }
```